# angular js show only the last data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, for-loop

I have two tables, customers and lists, lists hat a foreign key and must show the lists that a customer have. The lists are many, the customer ist only one. One to many in mysql.

```
$scope.getCustomer = function (id) {

      $http.get("/customers/getone/" + id)

      .then(function successCallback (response, data, status, headers, config) {

          $('#edit').modal('show');

          $scope.nameC = response.data[0].nameC;
          $scope.id=id;
          //$scope.clearForm()

          for (i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {

            $scope.nameL = response.data[i].nameL;
            //alert($scope.nameL);

        }



       },

  function errorCallback(error, data, status, haders, config) {
      console.log('Error getting: ' + data);

   });
}
```

I have with alert all lists, but in html have I only the last list. I have a ng-repeat to show all the customers. I want a ng-repeat or a ng-bind to show one customer and all the lists to the selected customer

```
<label>Name Kunde</label>
                 <td>
                 <span ng-bind="nameC"></span>
              </td>
              <br>
              <label>Name Liste</label>
              <td>
              <span ng-bind="nameL"></span>
           </td>



           <table class="table table-bordered">  
            <tr>  
                 <th>Name Listen</th>

            </tr>  

            <tr ng-repeat="data in [nameL] track by $index">  

             <td>{{data}}</td>  


             <td>



               </td>
            </tr>  
       </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get all the lists to display, you will need to store alle the lists in your scope. At this moment you only store the last list in your scope.

```
$scope.lists = [];

for (i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
    $scope.nameL = response.data[i].nameL;
    $scope.lists.push(nameL);
    //alert($scope.nameL);
}
```

then display your list of lists in you HTML

```
<table class="table table-bordered">  
    <tr>  
        <th>Name Listen</th>
    </tr>  
    <tr ng-repeat="data in lists track by $index">  
         <td>{{data}}</td>  
         <td>
         </td>
    </tr>  
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you very much: Here must be: $scope.lists.push($scope.nameL); 1 point for the useful answer :) Thanks